# Insights for Google Posts

Tags: google-my-business

We have recently started using Google Posts. However, I cannot see any details for Google Posts within the insights tab. Does anyone know if there is any insight available?

Answer (score 1):

I have insights available for a Post I was running for a Google Partners Event. Shows impressions and engagement *yawn*

[image: Google My Business Posts Insights]
[image: Google My Business Posts Insights]